# Checkbox always cheked if property specified?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, pug

This is driving me completely nuts. I can't figure out how to check/uncheck a checkbox through JavaScript.

I have the following in my HTML file:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input id="hardhat" type="checkbox" name="hardhat" checked="false" class="flat"/> Does the employee need his own hardhat?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which translates to this in Jade:

```
.form-group
  label.col-sm-3.control-label
    .col-sm-9
      .checkbox
         input#hardhat(type='checkbox', name='hardhat', class='flat', checked='false')
                            |  Does the employee need his own hardhat?
```

Having the checked property in HTML will ALWAYS open the window with the checkbox checked. The only way to uncheck the checkbox is to remove the checked property. What am I missing?

Because of this, nothing I do in JavaScript to check/uncheck the checkbox works :(. I was trying this:

```
var $modal = $('#editJob');
$modal.find('input#hardhat')['checked']=true;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### EDIT:

```
function showJobInfo(event) {

document.getElementById('editJob').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('editJob').style.visibility = "visible";

// Prevent Link from Firing
event.preventDefault();

// Retrieve job title from link rel attribute
var thisJobTitle = $(this).attr('rel');

// Get Index of object based on id value
var arrayPosition = userJoblistData.map(function(arrayItem) { return arrayItem.title; }).indexOf(thisJobTitle);

// Get our Job Object
var thisJobObject = userJoblistData[arrayPosition];

// Populate the edit job popup window
var $modal = $('#editJob');
$modal.find('input#jobTitle').val(thisJobObject.title);
$modal.find('input#payRate').val(thisJobObject.payrate);
$modal.find('input#startDate').val(thisJobObject.durationstart);
$modal.find('input#endDate').val(thisJobObject.durationend);
$modal.find('input#workingHours').val(thisJobObject.workinghrs);
$modal.find('input#location').val(thisJobObject.location);

$('#hardhat').prop('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: You should be clearer, is the `$` representing jQuery here? If so, that's the problem!

Comment: `document.querySelector('#hardhat').checked=true; //checked`, `document.querySelector('#hardhat').checked=false; //unchecked` I believe checked is a binary attribute, the element is checked if the attribute is present, unchecked without the attribute, ie, setting it to false doesn't make any sense and won't make a difference

Comment: @chiliNUT I agree about the checked attribute. The only way for me to have the checkbox unchecked is to remove the attribute. But if I remove it from my jade file and then try to check it like you listed....it does not get checked.

Comment: Learn the difference between attributes and properties. The `checked` property is a boolean, and setting it to `false` unchecks the checkbox -> https://jsfiddle.net/z0dm8tbr/

Comment: I don't know jade, but if you need to hit it with a hammer and remove the attribute entirely you should be able to do `document.querySelector('#hardhat').removeAttribute('checked')`

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what is the problem. If you want always checked, add  checked="true" html attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/yw3obrrt/

```
<input id="hardhat" type="checkbox" name="hardhat" checked="true" class="flat"/>
```

Check in jade that checked='true'

```
input#hardhat(type='checkbox', name='hardhat', class='flat', checked='true')
                            |  Does the employee need his own hardhat?
```

For test, not use F5 because remember your selection.

If not works.. try with jquery and use

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     $("#hardhat").attr("checked",true);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yw3obrrt/1/

Answer (score 0):

In your example!!

```
$('#hardhat').prop('checked', false);
```

This line, unchecked checkbox!

Change to

```
$('#hardhat').attr('checked', true);  // attr or prop
```

or comment this and add checked="true" in the html input!